# Ace editor, cursor position is above the actual text

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, ace-editor, cursor-position

I have this code in `Razor` page:

```
<td>
      <textarea class="MSSQL" id="MyId">
          My code
      </textarea>
</td>
```

And I'm using jquery to build the ace editor:

```
$('textarea.MSSQL').each(function () {
            var textarea = $(this);
            console.log(this);
            var editDiv2 = $('<div>', {
                position: 'absolute',
                width: "100%",
                height: "200px",
                'class': textarea.attr('class'),
                'Id': textarea.attr('id')
            }).insertBefore(textarea);
            textarea.css('visibility', 'hidden');
            var editor1 = ace.edit(editDiv2[0]);
            editor1.getSession().setValue(textarea.val().trim());
            editor1.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/sql");
            editor1.setTheme("ace/theme/sqlserver");
            editor1.setReadOnly(true);
            editor1.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
        });
```

Everything is working fine, except the cursor of the editor, his position is above the actual text, I've googled about the problem, most of cases are that the cursor is a few steps in the right or in the left of the actual text and the solution was to change the font to `monospace`. But it is not the case here.
Any suggestions?!

> Blockquote

Comment: may be a a conflict with some css on your page, try creating jsbin (or code snippet here) reproducing the issue

Comment: I think it is a conflict with a css property, because it's working fine in JSFiddle. I'm trying to findout the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in the main css file, there was a code that changing the `Line-height` of the the `span`, and because the ace editore set every single word in a span so that was causing the problem of the position.